# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}{s_n}$ if $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{k^{q-1}}{n^q+k^q}}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $p>0$, $q>1$, and $k \in\mathbb{N}$. Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}{s_n}$ if $$s_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{k^{q-1}}{n^q+k^q}}.$$

I try to link this to integral but failed. Anyone can give me some hint to think about?

Comment: This is the Riemann sum of $$\int_0^1 \frac{x^{q-1}}{1+x^q} dx = \frac{1}{q}[\ln (1+x^q)]_0^1 = \frac{\ln 2}{q}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide the fraction by $n^q$:
$$ \frac{k^{q-1}}{n^q+k^q} = \frac{k^{q-1}/n^q}{1-(k/n)^q} = \frac{1}{n} \frac{(k/n)^{q-1}}{1+(k/n)^q}, $$
and then the sum becomes a Riemann sum approximation of
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{x^{q-1}}{1+x^q} \, dx = \left[ \frac{1}{q}\log{(1+x^q)} \right]_0^1 = \frac{1}{q}\log{2}. $$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Fair point, added. Thanks.